# What is the relation between tuple and mapping which can be given as argument into "object Form"

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In scala play, a form can be created as :

```
val userForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "name" -> text,
    "age" -> number
  )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
)
```

or :

```
val loginForm = Form(
  tuple(
    "email" -> text,
    "password" -> text
  )
)
```

I have digged into Form.scala in github. And the code piece that makes these possible is as follows :

```
object Form {
/**
* Creates a new form from a mapping.
*
* For example:
* {{{
* import play.api.data._
* import play.api.data.Forms._
* import play.api.data.format.Formats._
*
* val userForm = Form(
* tuple(
* "name" -> of[String],
* "age" -> of[Int],
* "email" -> of[String]
* )
* )
* }}}
*
* @param mapping the form mapping
* @return a form definition
*/
def apply[T](mapping: Mapping[T]): Form[T] = Form(mapping, Map.empty, Nil, None)
```

My questions are :

1- What is `mapping`? I cannot find it. I suppose it should be something like `object mapping` or at least `case class mapping` ? I cannot find it in the source code.

2- I also dont understand the part after `mapping()`, where `(User.apply)(User.unapply)` is added. It is said they are to construct and deconstruct the Form. I dont quite get it though.

3- How can tuple can be used in place of `Mapping` ? In the api, I cannot find any clue that they are related at all.

Thank you.

Comment: Object `Forms` in play.api.data.Forms module has these methods `mapping` and `tuple`.

Comment: And so ? mapping is given as argument to Form object's apply method. What you say has no relation to this topic. Am I wrong ? Also, although still unrelated, Form has no method called tuple. And what is "Forms" ? Do you mean "Form" ?

Comment: I found Forms in the api. But it seems like they are not related, are they ?

Comment: @ShyamendraSolanki You were right. I understand it now. Sorry, and thank you : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuple in play forms are simple Tuples in scala, while mapping lets you to map your form into your own type like case class ,an example of this can be.

```
case class User(name:String,age:Int)
```

if you want to your form to be mapped to case class then you can do like this,

```
val userForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "name" -> text,
    "age" -> number
  )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
)
```

and then you can directly bind your case class User to your form-data by

```
 val res = request.bindFormRequest.get
```

here `res` will be of the type `User` or an instance of `User` class

but you can simply use tuple for this like,

```
val userForm = Form(
  tuple(
    "email" -> text,
    "password" -> text
  )
)
```

and get the result as follows

```
 val res = request.bindFormRequest.get
```

here `res` will be of the type `(String,Int)` and you can access name and age as `res._1` , `res._2` resp.

Now, coming to your mapping function explanation. `mapping` function takes two other functions `apply` and `unapply`. `apply` and `unapply` methods are used to convert form one form to other form. Eg:

```
 object User {
    def apply(name: String, age: Int) = {
      name + "," + age.toString
    }

    def unapply(nameAndAge: String) = {
      val r = nameAndAge.split(",")
      (r.head, r.last)
    }
  }

  println(User("curious", 23))

  println(User.unApply("curious,23"))
```

Here, `apply` method takes two parameters name and age of String and Int type resp. converts it to a `String` after concatenating them and `unapply` takes a String Type parameter and returns a String and Int type parameters. i.e `apply` and `unapply` methods are like ,`A=>T` and `T=>A` resp.

for more information on forms you can refer to play framework's Doc.
for more refrence on `Mapping` trait the source code is here.
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Form.scala

Comment: Thank you. I understand why we give the constructor and deconstructor. But I do not understand what the mapping is, and the function mapping returns in which we can give User.apply as argument.

Comment: Edited to explain apply and unapply methods, have a look at it.

Comment: As you can see in my question, here we use object Form. Object form's apply method takes Mapping trait as argument. However we use, something named, "mapping". Possibly an object. Where is this ? What kind of a function does it return which takes in a function as argument? All the things you have said, I have already known. I think I am having trouble explaining myself. You are telling me what the tutorial has already did. Where is "mapping"? Most importantly, what is "mapping"? CAREFUL HERE: Not "Mapping" , But "mapping" .

Comment: You can look at all the functions defined here, and "mapping" too :  https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Forms$@mapping%5BR%2CA1%5D((String%2CMapping%5BA1%5D))((A1)%E2%87%92R)((R)%E2%87%92Option%5BA1%5D)%3AMapping%5BR%5D

Comment: AAAAAAAaah, now I get it. In tutorials they add everything in Forms object as helper methods. Thank you. That is silly of me.